# Magento admin dashboard showing after login

Tags: admin, composer, dashboard, acl, klarnacheckout

My admin dashboard after logging in is showing the following error:

[image: Admin error]

does any one know the reason behind it
or how can we solve it?

I have recently installed this module through composer

I have recently Installed this module through composer

https://marketplace.magento.com/klarna-m2-checkout.html

Comment: you have added any acl file recently ??

Comment: May be It is added previously in any module

Comment: I recently installed klarna checkout module

Comment: through composer

Comment: please attach acl file

Comment: attched the code

Comment: magento version ??

Comment: magento version is 2.3.5

Comment: disable this module and check

Comment: please attach system.xml file

Comment: No It still shows error after disabling the module

Comment: this issue of another module.. before install this module you can change any acl.xml or system.xml file ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115373/discussion-between-anonymous-record-and-rk-rathod).